# VLQ flag declined, but answer deleted anyway

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

An answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111029/how-to-find-the-average-colour-of-an-image-in-python-with-opencv/49962068#49962068) question came up in my review queue.

The answer was a one-line wrong code. I do not remember exactly, but it was something like

```
average_color = cv2.mean(image)
```

I had flagged it as Very Low Quality. But my flag was declined by a moderator stating that

*'flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention.'*

[image]

Now maybe I have not got that answer code exactly right, but I remember it was a one-liner trying to find mean of an image and assign to average color. Now does not such an answer require a very low quality flag?

And if this was not worthy of a mod's intervention, why delete it later anyway?

I'm trying to understand what happened here, so I can improve my review process.

Comment: It wasn't deleted by a mod...it was deleted because 4 regular users with that privilege reviewed the answer and voted to delete it. The system worked. The mod didn't **need** to be involved and so declined the flag.

Comment: Oh, okay, agree a mod didn't need to involved. But then there's no option at least with my privilege to vote to close/delete. And declining my flag doesn't make sense to me here, because I too voted to delete it right?

Comment: The system worked, but my flag is not considered helpful even when it was, that's my concern. What could I have done to avoid a 'declined' flag?

Comment: Your flag was not helpful because it wasted the time of a moderator who could be processing flags that do require mod intervention. All you can do at the moment is downvote such posts. Once you get more rep your options will widen.

Comment: A moderator did get involved, he undeleted the post after it got deleted by the reviewers.  Yikes.  But a good reminder that the flag feature has become truly useless, you'll be ahead next time by downvoting it.

Comment: @HansPassant Do note that the moderator who undeleted the post was not involved in declining the flag. The post should have remained undeleted, and it was the review queue which wrongly deleted it.

Comment: @BhargavRao so... what would be the difference between deleted by 20kers and deleted by the queue? It would be the very same thing!

Comment: @Braiam not sure where I mentioned about 20kers deleting stuff ... but anyway, it depends on when the 20kers delete it. If they delete it after  the flag on the post has been invalidated, the particular review won't appear as an audit.

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm more interested in the results and how are they achieved. Is a waste of resources overriding reviewers so 20kers need to use votes, which should be used anyways.

Comment: Not quite sure if I follow you @Braiam, I didn't override 20kers. Just undeleted after the review queue deleted it. None of the 20k delete votes were harmed in the process.